# upload to mysql server not working

Tags: php, ios, sql, objective-c

I need to add data to my mysql database.However nothing is being added to the actual database below is my xcode and below that is my php code. Can't seem to see why it doesn't work? Any suggestions / can you see the error?

```
-(void) postMessage:(NSString*) teamid withPlayerid:(NSString *) playerid withFixtureid:(NSString *) fixtureid withEventid:(NSString *) eventid withHalfid:(NSString *) halfid{

//check isnt receiving two anit paramters
if(teamid !=nil && playerid !=nil && fixtureid !=nil && eventid !=nil && halfid !=nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kTeamid, teamid]];
    //makes kname equal to name
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kPlayerid , playerid]];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kFixtureid, fixtureid]];
    //makes kname equal to name
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kEventid , eventid]];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kHalfid, halfid]];
    //makes kname equal to name

    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",teamid);
    NSLog(@"%@",KTeamid);


}
}

-(IBAction)prop1Button:(id)sender{
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"1 - Prop"];

 _textField3.text = myString;
[self postMessage: self.textField2.text withPlayerid:self.textField3.text withFixtureid:self.textField3.text withEventid:self.textField3.text withHalfid:self.textField3.text];
_textField2.text = nil;
_textField3.text = nil;
dropGoalCounter ++;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DoUpdateLabel" object:nil userInfo:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Here is my php code for inserting into the database

```
<?php
include ("./inc/connect.inc.php");
$teamid = (int)$_POST["teamid"];
$playerid = (int)$_POST["playerid"];
$fixtureid = (int)$_POST["fixtureid"];
$eventid = (int)$_POST["eventid"];
$half = $_POST["halfid"];

$query = "INSERT INTO MatchEvent (MatchEventID, TeamID, PlayerID,FixtureID,EventID,Half) VALUES ('','9','1','8','7','$half')";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error("error"));

mysql_close();

?>
```

EDIT!!!
This now enters a new entry into the database but all the fields are blank im assuming because of the NSString and in the database the columns are integers. yet when i change the php to this

```
$teamid = (int)$_POST["teamid"]
$playerid = (int)$_POST["playerid"];
$fixtureid = (int)$_POST["fixtureid"];
$eventid = (int)$_POST["eventid"];
$half = (int)$_POST["halfid"];
```

It doesnt add an entry to the database at all. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Spot the problem:

xCode:

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                         ^^^^^
```

PHP:

```
$teamid = $_GET["teamid"];
            ^^^----hmmmmm. not $_POST
```

on top of this, you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Thanks changed that.. but it still isn't loading it into the database

Comment: NSLOG is showing that teamid,playerid etc are number 7 which is what i wanted, but its not loading into the database

Comment: so? the problem is your PHP code. You're sending an HTTP **POST** to the server, but are trying to read the data as if it was an HTTP **GET**. They're **NOT** compatible in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
include 'connection.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query = "INSERT INTO Register (username,password,firstname,lastname,email) VALUES   ('$username', '$password', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email')";
```

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

```
echo $query;
```

mine looks like this and works without error

Comment: thanks they are coming as zeros because they are strings and the table columns are integers i assume so ive put change the code like this `$eventid = (int)$_POST["eventid"];` etc when i do that nothing appears in the database any more. Any suggestions?

Comment: rather than int just keep it as VARCHAR its much simpler see for me the only int i have is for the user_id which would be auto increment

Comment: the reason they are ints is because they are foreign keys of the primary key of other tables.

Answer (score 0):

S[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kHalfid, halfid]]; has a ? instead of &.